# Why Kaira preferred disorganizing in her house?

Tags: character, dear-zindagi

In *Dear Zindagi*, Kaira is shown disorganizing decorative objects just after her maid organised them all. She even argues with her maid that she likes it that way only. But on the other hand, in her cinematography, she wants perfection.

I know that her character was having psychological issues due to her past. But what is the significance of making house disorganizing even when it doesn't go with her other personality traits?